# SQL Server Analysis Service Freezes When Connecting

Tags: sql-server, ssas, ssms

So I had to uninstall reinstall SQL Server 2012. In doing so I seem to have screwed Analysis Services.

When I attempt to connect to it via SQL Server Management Studio, SSMS just hangs indefinetly while MSSQLServerOLAPService logs

```
OLE DB error: OLE DB or ODBC error: [DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (Connect()).]SQL Server does not exist or access denied.; 08001.
```

in the event viewer.

Trying the Deployment Wizard logs

```
Errors in the metadata manager. An error occurred when loading the SOMECUBE cube, from the file, '\\?\C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSAS11.MSSQLSERVER\OLAP\Data\CUBE.0.db\SOMECUBE.4.cub.xml'.
```

Note that `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSAS11.MSSQLSERVER\OLAP` does not exist.

From Visual Studio the MSAS part of the project is labeled as `(incompatible)`.

I can see the service `SQL Server Analysis Services (MSSQLSERVER)` as `Started`.

Also, when I check the install (by trying to install an addon) I can see that SQL Server Analysis Services is already installed.

I'm thinking that the cubes from my old install are causing me grief, but I'm unsure how to go about correcting the problem.

EDIT: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSAS11.MSSQLSERVER\OLAP` does, I missed the MSAS part...Also this does have files left over from last install.

EDIT: Cleaning out the folder allowed me to add cubes but I cannot process them yet. Says sql server  instance does not exist

Answer (score 0):

So I after I realized I read the folder correctly going to

`C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSAS11.MSSQLSERVER\OLAP`

and cleaning out the XML documents and folders from the previous install allowed me to get a connection to Analysis Services.

From there I could deploy cubes; however, they could not process.

I fixed that by changing `localhost` to `PCNAME` and a connection could be established and processing started to work.